# Create a program in python that displays rainfall

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm supposed to create a program that uses specific rainfall numbers(does not ask user to input numbers) to output every month's rainfall, average, total, min, and max. My program should look like this:

```
Austin Tx Rainfall 2009

Jan    0.40

Feb    0.94

Mar    3.21

Apr    3.74

May    1.73

Jun    1.03

Jul    1.27

Aug    2.58

Sep    6.98

Oct    6.90

Nov    2.80

Dec      2.53

Total   34.11

Average 2.84

Max    6.98

Min    0.40
```

This is what I have so far:

```
amount = []
total = 0
month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
am =[0.4,0.94,3.21,3.74,1.73,1.03,1.27,2.58,6.98,6.9,2.8,2.53]
for j in range(len(am)):
    total+=j
print('Austin Tx Rainfall 2009')
print ("Month\t\tTotal Rainfall")
for i in range(len(month)):
    print (month[i], "\t\t", amount[i])
#total
print ("Total:\t\t ", total)
#average
average = total/12
print ("Average:\t",average)
min=min(am)
max=max(am)
print("min:\t",min)
print("max:\t",max)
```

however, when I run it, it returns this:

```
print (month[i], "\t\t", amount[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
*another question, when I try to add the rainfall amounts, the total accumulates the index number instead, so the total becomes 66(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11). How would I get the total to add the actual data?

Comment: of course, amount is an empty list when you reach that line. So index `i` will be out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `amount` is empty. You probably want

```
print (month[i], "\t\t", am[i])
```

Comment: ah, thank you! can't believe I didn't figure that out

Answer (score 1):

your amount list is empty
and your total should be like this:

for j in range(len(am)):
    total= total + am[j]

Answer (score 1):

With some rewriting:

```
COLUMNS = "{:<12} {:>4}".format

months  = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
amounts = [0.4,0.94,3.21,3.74,1.73,1.03,1.27,2.58,6.98,6.9,2.8,2.53]

def main():
    print('Austin Tx Rainfall 2009')

    print(COLUMNS("Month", "Total Rainfall"))
    for month, amount in zip(months, amounts):
        print(COLUMNS(month, amount))

    print(COLUMNS("Total:", sum(amounts)))
    print(COLUMNS("Average:", sum(amounts) / len(amounts)))
    print(COLUMNS("Min:", min(amounts)))
    print(COLUMNS("Max:", max(amounts)))

main()
```

which gives

```
Austin Tx Rainfall 2009
Month        Total Rainfall
Jan           0.4
Feb          0.94
Mar          3.21
Apr          3.74
May          1.73
Jun          1.03
Jul          1.27
Aug          2.58
Sep          6.98
Oct           6.9
Nov           2.8
Dec          2.53
Total:       34.11
Average:     2.8425
Min:          0.4
Max:         6.98
```